# Uso de Thread en Android

Tags: java

La vista contiene un botón, cuando se carga, el programa "pulsa" el botón, cuya función es llamar a un servidor, de tal modo que si los datos se actualizan en el servidor, el usuario pulsa el botón para que se realice de nuevo la llamada y los datos se actualicen. En el código del `MainActivity.java` tengo un método que ejecuta un Thread, dicho Thread realiza una llamada a esos servidores:

```java
//package...

//imports...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button boton;
    Thread tarea;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        boton = findViewById(R.id.botonReload);
        boton.performClick();
    }

    public void recargar(View view) {
        tarea = new Thread(() -> {
            //Conexión con servidores...
        });
        tarea.start();
    }
}
```

Sin embargo, puede darse la situación de que el usuario pulse en repetidas ocasiones el botón, causando que la ventana actual se congele. Según lo que he leído en otras publicaciones, esto puede deberse a dos factores:

- Ejecutar un `Thread` en el hilo principal, lo que puede causar un congelamiento de la pantalla, como está sucediendo; y más aún si es realizando conexiones con servidores. Menciono que estas conexiones se realizan con `openStream` y al final se cierra esa conexión,
- El segundo factor se complementa, en cierto modo, con el anterior, y es que no se está ejecutando en segundo plano.

En teoría, se puede ejecutar en segundo plano con `ExecutorService` o similar, pero desconozco como se hace.

Sumado a esto, cuando finalizo el `Thread`, llamo a un método que detiene la tarea: `tarea.interrupt()`, aún así, el hilo sigue activo:

```java
public void recargar(View view) {
    tarea = new Thread(() -> {
        //Conexiones con servidores...
        finalizar();
    });
    tarea.start();
}

private void finalizar() {
    tarea.interrupt();
    System.out.println(tarea.isAlive()); //Devuelve 'true'
}
```

Por lo tanto el usuario va creando varios hilos que nunca finalizan, y estos van ocupando memoria, hasta que la aplicación colapsa. Es una teoría.

La pregunta es:
¿Cómo pasar esa tarea a segundo plano? ¿Una vez que finaliza el código del Thread este muere? ¿Alguna recomendación de rendimiento o de causas de este suceso?

Comment: Hola, es demasiado importante revisar [ask] para evitar el cierre de tu pregunta, si deseas opinones puedes ir a [chat], saludos.

Comment: Antes de elaborar una hipótesis debes ver los datos que tienes. Necesitamos que cargues los errores que genere la aplicación. De lo contrario no podremos ayudarte. Puedes usar logcat, estar atento a la ventana `Run` de Android Studio o debugear la aplicación para ver los errores.

Comment: @Mateo ya está editado

Comment: tienes habilitado logcat, es de suma importancia la salida y el seguimiento de la aplicacion. como te comento Mateo, necesitamos eso para ayudarte con el debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android recomienda el uso de `Executors`, te dejo un ejemplo básico que se adapta a tus necesidades.

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    }

    private void reload(){
        executorService.execute(() -> {
            //tu código
        });
    }
```

*"Sin embargo, puede darse la situación de que el usuario pulse en repetidas ocasiones el botón".*

Bueno no debería de darse esta situación, evidentemente si estas haciendo una llamada muy pesada y porque no controlas los clicks del usuario creas 10 hilos iguales es posible que la CPU del dispositivo no lo soporte, para esto lo mas básico es una `ProgressBar` para indicar que "algo" se esta cargando, espero que tu problema se solucione.

Comment: Sí, solucionado, muchas gracias